# How do I create a pixel font?

Tags: fonts

I want to make a font that shows correctly when rendered by Windows at 7pt with no antialiasing at all.

I've tried FontStruct unsuccessfully, since I still can't figure out how many blocks should a 7pt large font be large. That's quite unfortunate, but it does not look like Fontstruct is going to get further updates.

Is there any way I can use Fontstruct to create that font? If not, what other application would allow me to do that?

---

To help with objectivity, here are some objective parameters of quality:

- (Linux only) Debian/Ubuntu packaging is preferred.
- The ability to prodce pixel map fonts (`.fon`) is preferred.
- Coverage of non-ASCII characters is preferred.

Comment: if you didn't mind a premade ttf or fon font, that renders great at a small size [tiny](http://www.squaregear.net/fonts/) and [damieneng's palm font](http://damieng.com/creative/typography/palmos-font) might work well, or at least give you an idea of what to use, designwise

Comment: @Journey Those fonts look awesome, and just what I was looking for!

Comment: @gparyani The OP *has* described the specific problem they're trying to solve.

Comment: This is a *really* old question, and these sort of questions were perfectly alright at the time it was asked. There's a clear problem, though the eventual solution was something totally different.

Comment: @slhck The answers to this question made me post that comment and put a recommend closure flag, which I did without even reading the question. I've now read the question and deleted the comment.

Answer (score 1):

[FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Can you expand your answer to explain how it solves the issue?

Answer (score 1):

pt size is in inches, more exactly 1 point = 1/72 inch.  It is independent of screen and print resolution (measured in dots per inch).  And it is not related to pixels on your screen.

Therefore to display a 7 pt glyph on your screen requires that your OS translate it into appropriate dots for your given screen, which may be different than how it translates it for another screen or printer.

So back in the day we could do this, make a font which mapped directly into pixels and always the same pixels.  But gone are those days, unless of course you are only targeting a specific known display, which perhaps is what you're doing???

See [here](http://freetype.org/freetype2/docs/glyphs/glyphs-2.html#section-1).

Answer (score 0):

You will have serious kerning issues with Fontstruct.

FontForge is an effective open source outline font editor also designed to trace bitmap versions a font.
Here is documentation about [creating bitmap strikes](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/editexample8.html) and the [bitmap glyph view](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/bitmapview.html) window.